# Examples using Lungo.JS

Tags: javascript, frameworks

Is there any example on using Lungo.JS?

I'm trying to start developing a WebApp for mobile content... and I've found http://lungo.tapquo.com/ , but I can't seem to find examples.

Thanks in advance

Comment: But using phonegap is needed to use HTML5 and js too...i thougt that phonegap is a wrapper to use html5  on a device using its capabilitues...  And i lije the Lungoaproach... i need to test it...

Comment: From what I can see, Lungo does the same thing that PhoneGap does, just it has less features and nobody has heard of it. And it has little documentation too.

Comment: @Muu please, help me with that, because i see the phonegap, and just a js library to use html (webapp) on mobiles, but no structure app structure code, or UI to view, for example, lists, such as Lungo.JS does... (i think Lungo it's more close to Jquery Mobile than phonegap...)

Comment: Here are some phonegap tutorials: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/35501397/Tutorials It's possible you're right about jQuery mobile being more like it - in which case, use that! Again, there are tonnes more people involved in the community and tonnes of documentation for it.

Comment: thanks @Muu, i'll try it (at the moment, i'm using jQuery Mobile, but still a litle slow for me...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I heard about downloaded the examples and just had a quick play here > https://github.com/daithiw44/Lungo-WS-Node-oAuth. I heard about it and had a look. Its easy to use, clean and neat, I like it. Its only starting out but its a good start.

Answer (score 5):

You have a HOWTO here..

http://lungo.tapquo.com/documentation/

it is easy to make a test sample..

1 - on \app\app.js uncoment lng.App.init(...)

2 - remove the test section and paste this complet example (based on the howto):

```
   <section id="main">
      <header data-title="Title of section"></header>
      <article id="first_article"></article>
        <article id="second_article" class="list">
           <scroll id="main_scroll">
             <ul>
                <li data-icon="user">
                    <strong>@soyjavi</strong>
                    <small>Author of @Lungojs</small>
                </li>

                <li data-icon="user">
                    <strong>@pasku1</strong>
                    <small>Contributor of @Lungojs</small>
                </li>

                ...
             </ul>
        </scroll>
        </article>

        <footer class="toolbar">
            <nav>
                <a href="#first_article" class="article" data-icon="home"></a>
                <a href="#second_article" class="article" data-icon="user"></a>

                 <!-- This link is to view a different section -->
                <a href="#second" class="section" data-icon="right"></a>
            </nav>
        </footer>
    </section>

   <section id="second">
       <header data-back="home blue"></header>
       <!-- content -->
   </section>
```

3- if you want more, there are screencasts: http://vimeo.com/user9162294

[edited]

4 - I have seen that there are examples on github: https://github.com/TapQuo/Lungo.js/tree/master/examples

Comment: as you can se you can navigate between "sections" and "articles" via href=”#<section/article name>” and tagin the link with class=”<section/article>”

you can doit using JS api too: http://www.lungojs.com/api/#doc-router-section

Answer (score 1):

The example is surprisingly enough in the example folder:  https://github.com/tapquo/Lungo.js/tree/master/example

You can also play with it directly by going to: http://lungo.tapquo.com/demo/